# Can I use a posthoc test with two significant main effects and no significant interaction?

Tags: interaction, post-hoc

I've found similar posts have been asked here, but not exactly with the same question.

I have a binary outcome variable (dep V M vs F) and two binary predictors, let´s say predictor 1, with levels 1A and 1B, and predictor 2, with level 2A and 2B.

The output of my generalized linear mixed effects model gives two significant main effects for both predictors (1 and 2), but no significant interaction between the two. As far as I understand, I should interpret this as: there is a difference regarding the distribution of M vs F between levels 1A and 1B and also between levels 2A and 2B. The fact that the interaction is not significant means that it is not the case that the effect of variable 1 is bigger/smaller for 2A than for 2B or, vice versa, that the effect of variable 2 is bigger/smaller for 1A than 1B.

From what I've learned in stats courses, you're not supposed to do post hoc tests if an interaction is not significant. But what if I don't want to know about the **relative difference** between the effect of variable 1 between conditions 2a and 2B, but rather whether the effect is present **at all** in both 2A and 2B. I've done a Tukey post hoc test that shows that the effect of variable 1 is present in 2A but not 2B. This is relevant for my research question, but I'm wondering if this is justifiable, even though the interaction itself was not significant. Any insights are welcome, as well as paper I could refer to that confirm my intuition that is **is** justifiable

Comment: Re. point 1: The non-significant interaction means that you can interpret the main effects independently one from the other, not that one is bigger than the other. In other words, the difference between levels 1A and 1B is independent of the level of predictor 2. The magnitude of each effect can be quantified the usual way (e.g., difference of means with 95% CI).

Comment: Thanks! I did not mean to say that an interaction would mean that the effect of one variable is bigger than that of the other, but that the effect of V1 is bigger in condition 2A than in 2B (or vice versa), i.e. that there is a different effect of V1 depending on the value of V2. But my question here is whether it is justifiable to do post hoc tests to know whether the effect of V1 is *present* in 2A vs. *absent* in 2B (which is a different question than whether the difference of the effect of V1 is *significantly bigger/smaller* in 2A from 2B). Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: My bad! I didn't read correctly. Re. "whether it is justifiable to do post hoc tests to know whether the effect of V1 is present in 2A vs. absent in 2B": Isn't this precisely what the interaction tell us?

Comment: I don't think so! I think the interaction just means that the effect of V1 is *different* for 2A than for 2B. This could mean several things: 1) it's significant in 2A, but not 2B, or 2) the other way around, or 3) the effect is not significant in either 2A or 2B but the direction of the effect is opposite which makes the interaction effect significant, or 4) the effect is significant in both 2A and 2B but still significantly stronger in one of the two...